# Приложение на C++ для работы с API: принцип работы

Tags: c++, алгоритм, http, запрос

Хочу написать своё приложение на C/C++ для работы с API [данного](http://www.reg.ru/reseller/API2-tech) регистратора. Я уже нашёл нужные мне функции в документации по работе с данным API, но совершенно не понимаю, как писать программу (консольное приложение) для работы с этим чудом :). Я понял, что мне нужно будет работать с HTTPS протоколом и библиотекой времени (time.h). Нашёл нужную мне библиотеку для C++ ([сама библиотека](http://curl.haxx.se/)).

Сформулировал вопрос по вашему совет:

1. Каков алгоритм работы с API (что должно происходить), отправка и получение, какими функциями?
2. Какой функцией я должен делать запрос (понял,что нужно licurl использовать)?
3. Какой функцией получать результат?

Объясните, пожалуйста, как мне писать и каков алгоритм, пишу свою первую нормальную программу.

*Ребят, если вы не поняли моего вопроса, пишите, что думаете. Просто, я первую программу пишу и вопросы сплошняком лезут.*

Благодарю!

Comment: Пока вопрос звучит так: "Как писать программы?" На этот вопрос нормально ответить нельзя, задайте более конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Подругому я не могу сказать. Я первый раз пишу, поэтому ваша формулировка верна. Пишите как знаете.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал вам писать это на Python или похожем высокоуровневом языке. Писать такое на C++, тем более в первый раз — очень странная идея. Вы закопаетесь в деталях и разочаруетесь в C++.

Comment: Для начала: что должна делать Ваша программа?

Comment: Если это какая-то сложная система, то не следует начинать изучение языка с этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если уже писал "Здравствуй Мир", попробуй для начала напиши, например, тест какой-нибудь в консоле, на айкью там или психологический, с этого начни, со стандартными функциями. Ну или чатик с нейросетью - задача нетривиальная, но все таки требует больше ума, нежели знаний и завлекательна. Крестики-нолики наконец, или лучше го-моку. А начинать с чуждого апи и непростых технологий, да, очень плохая идея для ПЕРВОЙ программы. В принципе можно даже и не в консоле начинать - например моя первая программа на срр (не считая учебных) была игра Гекс на OWL (была такая библиотека в Борланде), а там и шестиугольники надо было рисовать и циклы и события. В общем вывод - сложность может быть, но должна быть (ИМХО, конечно) алгоритмическая, а не технологическая, а то да, разочаруешься и забросишь.

Comment: НУ, это моя первая программа которую я буду использовать в жизни. Я уже писал много(в основном расчёт геометрическиз значений). То есть, я уже имею опыт(писал программы, таблицу цчашихся и средний бал). Я владею базовыми функциями. Я просто, не пойму какой функцией делать запрос и получать его.

Comment: Тогда советую найти примеры по кёрлу (библиотекам), на примерах лучше всего разобраться, потом попробовать самому что попроще (например скачать страницу майлру), а когда все проясниться поработать с регистратором.